# Brother HL-L2300D printer won't do anything on Ubuntu 20+ but worked before

Tags: printing

Ok, got an odd problem. Before my OS/apps drive was dying I had the printer listed above working fine. New HD, re-install of Ubuntu 20.04 and now the printer won't work at all.

1. I installed the brother printer install tool as before, and ran it without problems.
2. configured it though CUPS

*But nothing I've done will make the printer work.* I sent a test print for example, the light blinks as if it's getting a feed, and the printer turns on (I'm assuming that whirling is the drum starting up.) But nothing is printed. Finally it goes back to sleep.

I've tried Emacs print buffer (simple text), Thunderbird, Firefox browser page. Virtually the same thing.

I don't know how to send a print though the CLI, and I know at times that'll give me valuable insight. So anything?

Comment: I had a similar problem... Check messages in the `dmesg` output right after an attempt to print - do you see any messages with the word `DENIED`?